# What is the direction of induced manetic field?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

By Ampere-Maxwell's law, we know changing electric field induces a magnetic field. But this equation gives only the curl of magnetic field. What is the direction of induced magnetic field, not curl of it?
To simplify question, assume that there is a infinite straight wire with increasing line charge density λt. So the direction of electric field is just radial, and its amplitude is linearly increasing. Because the electric field is increasing, a magnetic field would be induced. Which direction, amplitude?

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in different manners, let's see one: let $\hat{z}$ be along the wire and $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$ be perpendicular to the wire. We can use the Maxwell's equation

$$\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{B}=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial t}$$

As you said before, the direction of the electric field is just radial, applying Gauss' theorem we find

$$\vec{E}=\frac{\lambda t x}{2\pi\epsilon_{0}(x^2+y^2)}\hat{x}+\frac{\lambda t y}{2\pi\epsilon_{0}(x^2+y^2)}\hat{y}$$

that means that the curl $\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{B}$ must be in the $xy$ plane. Since the curl is a particular outer product, the curl of a vector is always perpendicular to that vector, so we have $\vec{\nabla}\times \vec{B} \perp \vec{B}$. Thank to this relation we know that $\vec{B}$ only has $B_{z}$ component. For the amplitude calculus we can write the curl components along $\hat{x}$ and $\hat{y}$ and use the Maxwell's equation

$$\frac{\partial B_{z}(x,y)}{\partial y}=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\lambda x}{2\pi\epsilon_{0}(x^2+y^2)}$$

$$\frac{\partial B_{z}(x,y)}{\partial x}=-\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\lambda y}{2\pi\epsilon_{0}(x^2+y^2)}$$

Note that $B_{z}$ component is only depending on $x$ and $y$ since $\vec{\nabla}\cdot \vec{B}=0$. Using the above equations one can verify that the solution for the amplitude of $B_{z}$ is given by

$$ B_{z}(x,y)=\frac{1}{c^2}\frac{\lambda}{2\pi\epsilon_{0}}\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right) $$